# Is there a way to use a pre-existing json query in a java elastic query?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

So I have inherited some services where I have objects that hold a raw elastic query json (including aggregations/ordering/weights/etc.) and I was wondering if there was a way for me to use that existing json query sting in the java api instead of translating it into the java api's query dsl. Is this the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the [low level java api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.5/java-rest-low-usage-requests.html).

You can use a preexisting json using the method [`setJsonEntity`](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/6.5.2/org/elasticsearch/client/Request.html#setJsonEntity(java.lang.String)):

> **Set the body of the request**. If not set or set to null then no body is sent with the request.

Here a simple snippet of code:

```
String jsonString = ...
request.setJsonEntity(jsonString);
```